# How to get this function to be evaluated lazily

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
main = do xs <- getContents
          edLines <- ed $ lines xs
          putStr $ unlines edLines
```

Firstly I used the working version `main = interact (unlines . ed . lines)` but changed the signature of `ed` since. Now it returns `IO [String]` instead of just `[String]` so I can't use this convenient definition any more.

The problem is that now my function `ed` is still getting evaluated partly but nothing is displayed till I close the stdin via CTRL + D.

Definition of `ed`:

```
ed :: Bool -> [EdCmdLine] -> IO EdLines
ed xs = concatM $ map toLinesExt $ scanl (flip $ edLine defHs) (return [Leaf ""]) xs where
    toLinesExt :: IO [EdState] -> IO EdLines
    toLinesExt rsIO = do
         rs@(r:_) <- rsIO -- todo add fallback pattern with (error)
         return $ fromEd r ++ [" "]
```

The `scanl` is definitely evaluated lazy because `edLine` is getting evaluated for sure (observable by the side effects).

I think it could have to do with `concatM`:

```
concatM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m [a]) -> m [a]
concatM xsIO = foldr (\accIO xIO -> do {x <- xIO; acc <- accIO; return $ acc ++ x}) (return []) xsIO
```

Comment: Are you on Windows by any chance? Have you tried setting console buffering to "per line"?

Comment: No I'm not. Also, It just worked before the change of `ed` where I added the possibility of side effects. In addition to that the `scanl` part surly gets evaluated lazily "per line".

Comment: Well, yes, it is evaluated lazily, but then, as soon as you call `putStr`, all that laziness gets forced, because `putStr` needs the resulting string, and the `Show` instance needs all the data inside in order to produce that string. IO actions don't execute lazily, that's their whole point.

Comment: Oh, this just occurred to me: the difference between `interact` and `putStr` is that the former prints a newline, but the latter doesn't. Have you tried `putStrLn` instead?

Comment: No `putStrLn` doesn't resolve the issue. The [implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#interact) of `interact` also uses `putStr` though and with it everything worked flawlessly.Also why can't `putStr` just printout parts of a String? I think that's actually done because if you're trying to show an infinite list it works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I/O in Haskell is explicitly ordered. The last two lines of your `main` function desugar into something like

```
ed (lines xs) >>= (\edLines -> putStr $ unlines edLines)
```

`>>=` sequences all of the I/O effects on the left before all of those on the right. You're constructing an I/O action of the form `generate line 1 >> ... >> generate line n >> output line 1 >> ... >> output line n`.

This isn't really an evaluation order issue, it's a correctness issue. An implementation is free to evaluate in any order it wants, but it can't change the ordering of I/O actions that you specified, any more than it can reorder the elements of a list.

Here's a toy example showing what you need to do:

```
lineProducingActions :: [IO String]
lineProducingActions = replicate 10 getLine

wrongOrder, correctOrder :: IO ()

wrongOrder = do
  xs <- sequence lineProducingActions
  mapM_ putStrLn xs

correctOrder = do
  let xs = [x >>= putStrLn | x <- lineProducingActions]
  sequence_ xs
```

Note that you *can* decouple the producer and consumer while getting the ordering you want. You just need to avoid combining the I/O actions in the producer. I/O actions are pure values that can be manipulated just like any other values. They aren't side-effectful expressions that happen immediately as they're written. They happen, rather, in whatever order you glue them together in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'm looking into this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [`unsafeInterleaveIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeInterleaveIO) to schedule some of your `IO` actions for later. Beware that the `IO` actions may then be executed in a different order than you might first expect!

However, I strongly recommend *not* doing that. Change your `IO [String]` action to print each line as it's produced instead.

Alternately, if you *really* want to maintain the computation-as-pipeline view, check out one of the many streaming libraries available on Hackage (streamly, pipes, iteratees, conduit, machines, and probably half a dozen others).

Comment: I already tried your suggested approach to just let `ed` return `[IO EdLines]` (so without `concatM`) and then print them out as they are produced via:

`main = do {xs <- getContents;
let printLine lineIO acc = do {line <- lineIO; putStr $ unlines line};
foldr printLine (return ()) (ed $ lines xs)}`

but this doesn't seem to work either and my program exits immediately without prompting for user input

Comment: @Toorero Your `printLine` does not mention `acc` in its body. That's probably the problem.

Comment: Ok I tried to integrate it but it still does not work. Also I tried to use sequence before concatM

Comment: I think the problem is: `concatM` (which now just unpacks the monad and then runs `concat`) need a full Monad, so it doesn't work lazy as `concat` does and I think `sequence` doesn't work lazy either.

But if I try to print them as they come directly it will either exit immediatly (if not properly integrating `acc`) or just wait for some weird reason for the whole list to complete...

I just have the suspision that the Monad `<-` doesn't work lazy

Comment: @Toorero If you have a different confusion about different code, feel free to create a new question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @benrg answer I was able to solve the issue with the following code:

```hs
ed :: [EdCmdLine] -> [IO EdLines]
ed cmds = map (>>= return . toLines . head) $ edHistIO where
    toLines :: EdState -> EdLines
    toLines r = fromEd r ++ [" "]

    edHistIO = edRec defHs cmds (return [initState])
    edRec :: [HandleHandler] -> [EdCmdLine] -> IO EdHistory -> [IO EdHistory]
    edRec _ [] hist = [hist]                                -- if CTRL + D
    edRec defHs (cmd:cmds) hist = let next = edLine defHs cmd hist in next : edRec defHs cmds next

main = getContents >>= mapM_ (>>= (putStr . unlines)) . ed . lines
```

Comment: This looks very, very convoluted. I recommend writing a variant of `edLine`, with a type like `notEdLine :: [HandleHandler] -> EdCmdLine -> EdHistory -> IO EdHistory`. Then you can write `ed :: [EdCmdLine] -> IO (); ed = go initState where go hist [] = pure (); go hist (cmd:cmds) = do hist' <- notEdLine defHs cmd hist; putStr . unlines . toLines . head $ hist'; go hist' cmds`.